# Show, using the definitions, that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf a_n = \infty$ implies that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

> Show, using the definitions, that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf a_n = \infty$ implies that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$

Here is the definition of $\liminf$ is

> $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}  a_n = \lim(\inf{a_k : k \geq n})$ where $a_n$ is a sequence

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @Kasper It's in the title. Not that it shouldn't be in the post, obviously.

Comment: prove that the statement is true using the definition of lim inf

Comment: The contrapositive may be easier to handle.

Comment: Is it similar to the proof of lim sup an as n tends to ∞ =-∞ implies lim an as n tends to ∞ = -∞ ?

Comment: @Megan People prefer it if you write math using $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Observe that: $\displaystyle \inf_{k\geq n} a_k \leq a_n $ (why?)

What does your assumption tell you about the LHS of this inequality?

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: What are you confused about? Try to formulate your difficulty so that we can help address it.